# sed doesn't work in bash script even though individual RegEx expressions seem to be correct

Tags: regex, sed

### What I'm trying to do

Bash script to replace the uncommented `php_version: "7.2"` with the a user-entered version:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask desired PHP version
read -p "What version of PHP should be used? (5.6, 7.0, 7.1, or 7.2): " phpVersion

# Replace default php version with desired php version
sed -i "s/^php_version: \"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\"/php_version: \"${phpVersion}\"/g" fileToSearchReplace.txt
```

Contents of `fileToSearchReplace.txt` which vim reports is a unix file:

```
APIVersion: v1.0.0
name: alpha-local
type: typo3
docroot: public
# php_version: "7.1"  # PHP version to use, "5.6", "7.0", "7.1", "7.2"
php_version: "7.2"
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
provider: default
```

### Diagnostics

*This worked:* **[I checked the RegEx here](https://regexr.com/3tplm)** using `^php_version: "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"` for search and `php_version: "7.0"` for replace (you can find replace and paste in the text a tab below. **Notice I could only get the search to work using the `/gm` at the end.** I have no idea how to get multiline to work in `sed`???

### Environment

- Windows 10 Pro host
- Using MINGW64 git bash terminal
- These files are part of a Docker container
- I tried running this `sed` both in my MINGW64 git bash terminal and also inside the Ubuntu container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `+` with sed by default. Either do your own `+` like that:

```
sed -i "s/^php_version: \"[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\"/php_version: \"${phpVersion}\"/g" fileToSearchReplace.txt
```

Or use the extended regex option `-r`:

```
sed -r -i "s/^php_version: \"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\"/php_version: \"${phpVersion}\"/g" fileToSearchReplace.txt
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/PowderblueFoolishEquipment

Comment: Thank you for explaining the `-r` option for extended regex support in`sed`. This is the closest to what I was looking in an explanation of why is wasn’t working for me. @anubhava came in a close second though adding an alternative way that avoids using extended regex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its a good idea to try out a regex from a site which doesn't say which class of regex it is supporting and re-using the same in your command.

You have a classic case of mix-up in which the regex pattern from the site, is of the Extended Regular Expressions and the one in your `sed` uses Basic Regular expression construct which does not support your `[0-9]+` expression. Simply enable the ERE support with the `-E` switch in your `sed`

```
sed -Ei "s/^php_version: \"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\"/php_version: \"${phpVersion}\"/g" fileToSearchReplace.txt
```

See the [ [POSIX](https://sed.js.org/?gist=ae45973fcdd787b0293ac349fac4ff0e) | [GNU](https://sed.js.org/?gist=89d32a26f41ca925a76b479f2f19b6e1) ] variants of the same solution, with the POSIX version using the BRE and the GNU version using ERE. Do read through this useful article on [POSIX Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) on how the two variants of the regular expressions work.

Comment: I didn't see `-E` as an option for `sed`... looks like it was `-r` in my case but you nailed it on the head about needing the extended regex, I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this script with `select` that lets user select a version from a menu list. You can then pass selected option to a simplified `sed` command:

```
select ver in "5.6" "7.0" "7.1" "7.2"; do
    sed -i "s/^\(php_version: \).\+/\1\"$ver\"/" fileToSearchReplace.txt
    break
done
```

Comment: I have tested this code and it works great. You took it to the next level for me too with the `select`. You also avoided having to use the `-r` option by using the `.` to match any character to the end of the line if I understand it correctly.